# ImportError: cannot import name _counter but _counter.pyd exists

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko, pycrypto

I am encountering the below stacktrace when running import paramiko (this is in windows platform)

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 50, in <module>
    from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 26, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/DSA.py", line 89, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import _UserFriendlyRNG
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 38, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random.Fortuna import FortunaAccumulator
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py", line 39, in <module>
    import FortunaGenerator
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py", line 35, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util import Counter
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Util/Counter.py", line 59, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util import _counter
ImportError: cannot import name _counter
```

I see that _counter.pyd exists in Pycrypto folder. Why is this not getting picked?